# Wheel of fortune. How rotate only to right and

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good day. The problem looks as follows.
I have a wheel of fortune, in which colors have a different order, but smaller in terms of appearance. To the fortune wheel are the assignment of degrees that I have written in the array. The wheel rotates automatically at a specified time. The problem that is quite important is that the wheel spins once to the left once to the right. The first question is how to avoid this in the sense that you wanted the wheel to turn to the right.

My code:

```
<div class="rl-time">00.00</div>
//img link is here becacues I don't have 10 points of reputation
//https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ee/WheelofFortune2.png
<div><img src="" alt="wh"></div>
```

css

```
img{
 width: 300px;
 transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
 will-change: transform;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

js

```
    var count = 100;
let degs = 0;

const items = [
  '0', '7', '13.5', '20', '26.5', '33.5', '40', '47', '53.5', '60',
  '66.5', '73.5', '80', '87', '93.5', '100', '107', '113.5', '120',
  '127','133.5', '140.2', '147', '153.5', '160.5', '167', '173.5',
  '180','187', '193.5', '200', '207', '213.5', '220', '227', '233.5',
  '240','247', '253.5', '260', '267', '273.5', '280', '287', '293.5', 
  '300', '307', '313.5', '320', '327', '333.5', '340', '347', '353.5'
 ];

function timer()
{
    var counter = setInterval(countdown, 10);
    function countdown(){
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $(".rl-time").text("00.00"); 

            spinIt();
            return;
        }
        count--;

        if(count < 1000){
            $(".rl-time").text("0" + (count /100).toFixed(2)); 
        }else{
            $(".rl-time").text((count /100).toFixed(2));
        }
    }

}

function spinIt() { 
            degs += parseInt(items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]) + 360;

    var css = 'transform: rotate('+degs+'deg)';
    $("img").attr('style', css);

    count = 100;
    setTimeout(function(){
        timer();
    }, 5700);

}




 timer();
```

You can see in my code:

```
degs += parseInt(items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]) + 360;
```

Of course, thanks to this, it spins only to the right, however it does not return the corresponding results from the items. Items are assigned the appropriate values that must be returned.
Well, I think You can help me or you'll give advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you try to explain your problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood your question: this may be helpful: put this in **`function spinIt()`**:

```
degs += 360 - degs % 360;
degs += 1*items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

var css = 'transform: rotate('+parseInt(degs)+'deg)';
```

to get what is an angle from your set: use simply: **`degs % 360`**.